# add and remove class depending on element height on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add and remove a class to two divs (#col-left and #col-right) depending on their height that dynamically changes when a tab button is pushed (they live in a toggle box).

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.btn').click(function () {

   var colLeftHeight = $("#col-left").height();
   var colRightHeight = $("#col-right").height();


  if (colLeftHeight > colRightHeight) {
     $("#col-left").addClass('border-right');
     $("#col-right").removeClass('border-left');
  }
  if (colRightHeight > colLeftHeight) {
     $("#col-right").addClass('border-left');
     $("#col-left").removeClass('border-right');
  }  
  });

</script>
```

It works, but the classes are only added/removed correctly on the second click of the button. I'm not sure what I am missing that's not triggering the first click. Thanks so much!

Edit:

Here's a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/kfj61bq6/

Specifically note when you click both the "code" buttons. On first click, the border doesn't extend (aka the class is not added), but the second time you click it, it's added and the border extends. Clicking "default" on the left and "code" on the right does this as well. Clicking "default" the second time adds the class correctly.

Comment: Could you show a working example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net? I can't see any specific reason in the code you've shown why that behaviour would occur.

Comment: A side note, put that code in `$(document).ready(function(){})` to make sure that all elements are loaded before you bind anything to them.

Comment: I don't have your exact html but it seems to be working just fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/by4cqx3r/1/

Comment: Because you HTML is not loaded yet, you should wait until the document is ready and then execute javascript and do all the bindings.

Comment: try binding the click to the document instead e.g ($(document).on('click', ''.btn'', function () { ... ) -- see if that helps